# In Rails 4 Guard is not updating the test count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, guard

I just upgraded to Guard 2 and it is is telling me there are 7 examples and 7 failures.

Here's the spec file i'm working on:

```
    # == Schema Information
    #
    # Table name: awardunits
    #
    #  id              :integer          not null, primary key
    #  nyaaid          :string(255)
    #  name            :string(255)
    #  address         :string(255)
    #  district        :string(255)
    #  contact         :string(255)
    #  email           :string(255)
    #  insthead        :string(255)
    #  instheadcontact :string(255)
    #  datestarted     :date
    #  allowedmem      :integer
    #  remarks         :text
    #  disabled        :boolean
    #  created_at      :datetime
    #  updated_at      :datetime
    #

    require 'spec_helper'

    describe Awardunit do
        before { @awardunit = Awardunit.new(nyaaid: "NYAA/N/WP0001", name: "Test Unit", address: "No. 50, Kalpitiya Road, Maradana", district: "Colombo", contact: "23232223", email: "abc@localhost.com", insthead: "Namal Kaluaarachchi", instheadcontact: "324234234", datestarted: "1/10/2013", allowedmem: "5", remarks: "" ) }

        it { should respond_to(:nyaaid) }
        it { should respond_to(:name) }
        it { should respond_to(:address) }
        it { should respond_to(:district) }
        it { should respond_to(:contact) }
        it { should respond_to(:email) }
        it { should respond_to(:insthead) }
        it { should respond_to(:instheadcontact) }
        it { should respond_to(:datestarted) }
        it { should respond_to(:allowedmem) }
        it { should respond_to(:remarks) }
        it { should respond_to(:disabled) }

        it { should be_valid }

        describe "when nyaaid is not present" do
            before { @awardunit.nyaaid = " " }
            it { should_not be_valid }
        end

        describe "when name is not present" do
            before { @awardunit.name = " " }
            it { should_not be_valid }
        end

        describe "when district is not present" do
            before { @awardunit.district = " " }
            it { should_not be_valid }
        end

        describe "when contact is not present" do
            before { @awardunit.contact = " " }
            it { should_not be_valid }
        end

        describe "when datestarted is not present" do
            before { @awardunit.datestarted = " " }
            it { should_not be_valid }
        end



        describe "when email format is invalid" do
            it "should be invalid" do
                addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo. foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
                addresses.each do |invalid_address|
                    @authentication.email = invalid_address
                    expect(@authentication.save).to be_false
                end
            end
        end

        describe "when email format is valid" do
            it "should be valid" do
                addresses = %w[user@foo.COM A_US-ER@f.b.org frst.lst@foo.jp a+b@baz.cn]
                addresses.each do |valid_address|
                    @authentication.email = valid_address
                    expect(@authentication.save).to be_true
                end
            end
        end 

    end
```

Its not including the top tests into the 7 examples! One problem, When I add a new describe block to a spec file and save, normally the count should go to 8 examples. But guard is still showing 7! If I go to a different spec file and save it, guard still say 7 examples and 7 failures according to the old file! How can I fix this issue?

`Guardfile` :

```
require 'active_support/inflector' 
notification :libnotify

guard :rspec, notification: true, all_on_start: true, cmd: 'spring rspec'  do
watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')  { "spec" }

# Rails example
watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$})                           { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
watch(%r{^app/(.*)(\.erb|\.haml|\.slim)$})          { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}#{m[2]}_spec.rb" }
watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$})  { |m| ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb", "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb", "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb"] }
watch(%r{^spec/support/(.+)\.rb$})                  { "spec" }
watch('config/routes.rb')                           { "spec/routing" }
watch('app/controllers/application_controller.rb')  { "spec/controllers" }

# Capybara features specs
watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/.*\.(erb|haml|slim)$})     { |m| "spec/features/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }

# Turnip features and steps
watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/(.+)\.feature$})
watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/steps/(.+)_steps\.rb$})   { |m| Dir[File.join("**/#{m[1]}.feature")][0] || 'spec/acceptance' }


  # Custom Rails Tutorial specs
watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$})  do |m|
  ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb",
   "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb",
   "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb",
   (m[1][/_pages/] ? "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" : 
                     "spec/requests/#{m[1].singularize}_pages_spec.rb")]
end
watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/}) do |m|
  (m[1][/_pages/] ? "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" : 
                     "spec/requests/#{m[1].singularize}_pages_spec.rb")
end
watch(%r{^app/controllers/sessions_controller\.rb$}) do |m|                                                                                                  
  "spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb"                                                                                                               
end
end
```

`Gemfile.lock` :

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.0.0)
      actionpack (= 4.0.0)
      mail (~> 2.5.3)
    actionpack (4.0.0)
      activesupport (= 4.0.0)
      builder (~> 3.1.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rack (~> 1.5.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
    activemodel (4.0.0)
      activesupport (= 4.0.0)
      builder (~> 3.1.0)
    activerecord (4.0.0)
      activemodel (= 4.0.0)
      activerecord-deprecated_finders (~> 1.0.2)
      activesupport (= 4.0.0)
      arel (~> 4.0.0)
    activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
    activesupport (4.0.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.4)
      minitest (~> 4.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.37)
    annotate (2.5.0)
      rake
    arel (4.0.1)
    atomic (1.1.14)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
    better_errors (1.0.1)
      coderay (>= 1.0.0)
      erubis (>= 2.6.6)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    bootstrap-sass (2.3.2.2)
      sass (~> 3.2)
    builder (3.1.4)
    capybara (2.1.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      xpath (~> 2.0)
    celluloid (0.15.2)
      timers (~> 1.1.0)
    childprocess (0.3.9)
      ffi (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.11)
    coderay (1.0.9)
    coffee-rails (4.0.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    diff-lcs (1.2.4)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.0.2)
    factory_girl (4.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.2.1)
      factory_girl (~> 4.2.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    faker (1.2.0)
      i18n (~> 0.5)
    ffi (1.9.0)
    font-awesome-rails (4.0.0.0)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 5.0)
    formatador (0.2.4)
    guard (2.1.1)
      formatador (>= 0.2.4)
      listen (~> 2.1)
      lumberjack (~> 1.0)
      pry (>= 0.9.12)
      thor (>= 0.18.1)
    guard-rspec (4.0.3)
      guard (>= 2.1.1)
      rspec (~> 2.14)
    hike (1.2.3)
    i18n (0.6.5)
    jbuilder (1.5.2)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.2.0)
    jquery-rails (3.0.4)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.1)
    libnotify (0.8.2)
      ffi (>= 1.0.11)
    listen (2.1.1)
      celluloid (>= 0.15.2)
      rb-fsevent (>= 0.9.3)
      rb-inotify (>= 0.9)
    lumberjack (1.0.4)
    mail (2.5.4)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    method_source (0.8.2)
    mime-types (1.25)
    mini_portile (0.5.2)
    minitest (4.7.5)
    modernizr-rails (2.6.2.3)
    multi_json (1.8.2)
    nokogiri (1.6.0)
      mini_portile (~> 0.5.0)
    pg (0.17.0)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    pry (0.9.12.2)
      coderay (~> 1.0.5)
      method_source (~> 0.8)
      slop (~> 3.4)
    rack (1.5.2)
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.0.0)
      actionmailer (= 4.0.0)
      actionpack (= 4.0.0)
      activerecord (= 4.0.0)
      activesupport (= 4.0.0)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.0.0)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0)
    rails_12factor (0.0.2)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.1)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.3)
    railties (4.0.0)
      actionpack (= 4.0.0)
      activesupport (= 4.0.0)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (10.1.0)
    rb-fsevent (0.9.3)
    rb-inotify (0.9.2)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0)
    rdoc (3.12.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    rspec (2.14.1)
      rspec-core (~> 2.14.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.14.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.14.0)
    rspec-core (2.14.6)
    rspec-expectations (2.14.3)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3, < 2.0)
    rspec-mocks (2.14.4)
    rspec-rails (2.14.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.14.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.14.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.14.0)
    sass (3.2.12)
    sass-rails (4.0.1)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0)
    sdoc (0.3.20)
      json (>= 1.1.3)
      rdoc (~> 3.10)
    slop (3.4.6)
    spring (0.0.11)
    sprockets (2.10.0)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (~> 2.8)
    thor (0.18.1)
    thread_safe (0.1.3)
      atomic
    tilt (1.4.1)
    timers (1.1.0)
    treetop (1.4.15)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    turbolinks (1.3.0)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (0.3.38)
    uglifier (2.2.1)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    xpath (2.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  annotate
  bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0.0)
  better_errors
  binding_of_caller
  bootstrap-sass
  capybara
  childprocess
  coffee-rails (~> 4.0.0)
  factory_girl_rails
  faker
  font-awesome-rails
  guard (~> 2.1.1)
  guard-rspec (~> 4.0.3)
  jbuilder (~> 1.2)
  jquery-rails
  libnotify
  modernizr-rails
  pg
  rails (= 4.0.0)
  rails_12factor
  rb-inotify
  rspec (~> 2.14.0)
  rspec-rails
  sass-rails (~> 4.0.0)
  sdoc
  spring
  turbolinks
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, Guard is adding `focus_on_failed: true` by default. In the Guard file, you have to add `focus_on_failed: false`. Here's how it will look like :

```
guard :rspec, notification: true, all_on_start: true, focus_on_failed: false, cmd: 'spring rspec'  do
```

Solution : https://github.com/guard/guard/issues/511